# Number of $AB$,$BA$ in permutations of $AAAAABBBB$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Find the number of $AB$ and $BA$ in the permutations of $AAAAABBBB$ (Ex: AABBAAABB contains 3).

So far, I could only solved it by principle of inclusion and exclusion. As far as I know, there is a better way.

Comment: What's your solution doing it your way?

Comment: @AndrewChin As I have written in my post above.

Comment: That's not a solution; that's not even an answer.  It's more like a proposal.

Comment: While I'm troubled by the lack of a clear statement of how "I could only solve it," even more troubling is the lack of a clear statement of what is to be counted.  Are you trying to count occurrences of $AB$ and $BA$ in one permutation (with repetitions)?  In all such permutations? Or is there some other interpretation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a probabilistic approach.  Consider a random permutation of $AAAAABBBB$; there are $9!$ such permutations, all of which are equally likely.  Define
$$X_i = 
\begin{cases}1 \qquad \text{if there is an AB starting at location i of the permutation}\\
0 \qquad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
and
$$Y_i = 
\begin{cases}1 \qquad \text{if there is a BA starting at location i of the permutation}\\
0 \qquad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
for $1 \le i \le 8$.
Then we have 
$$P(X_i = 1) = P(Y_i = 1) = \frac{4 \cdot 5}{9 \cdot 8}$$
so
$$E \left( \sum_{i=1}^8 (X_i +Y_i) \right) =  \sum_{i=1}^8 E(X_i) + \sum_{i=1}^8 E(Y_i) = 2 \cdot 8 \cdot \frac{4 \cdot 5}{9 \cdot 8} \tag{1}$$
by linearity of expectation.
On the other hand,
$$E \left( \sum_{i=1}^8 (X_i +Y_i) \right) = \frac{N}{9!} \tag{2}$$
where $N$ is the total number of occurrences of $AB$ and $BA$ in the complete set of $9!$ permutations.

Solve $(1)$ and $(2)$ for $N$ and you're done.

Edit, Dec. 20 2019:

Based on Milo Brandt's comment, below, if we are dealing with "distinguishable permutations", then the $9!$ in equation $(2)$ should be replaced with $\binom{9}{4}$.

Comment: I think your equation (2) isn't quite what is desired - for the combinatorics, we're probably counting any permutations that result in the same sequence of letters as the same, hence a denominator of ${9 \choose 4}$ would be more appropriate. (Though it's rather cool that, by passing to probabilities, the rest of your answer doesn't need to worry about this issue at all)

Comment: @MiloBrandt That's a good point.  It all depends on what kind of permutations we are counting.